# Tex Custom Arrow with oplus symbol

Tags: tikz-pgf, tex-core, tikz-arrows

I'd like to create the kind of arrow that shows inner classes in UML, that is, an arrow that starts with an `\oplus` symbol as it can be seen here: http://myumlnotes.blogspot.com.es/2007/01/inner-class.html with Tikz.

[image]

Anyone could help me define that arrow? 
Something like `\pgfarrowsdeclare{OPLUS arrow}{OPLUS arrow}`
could be perfect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the definition of the `o` arrows and add the plus with:

```
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0bp}{0bp}}%
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{9\pgfutil@tempdima}{0bp}}%
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{4.5\pgfutil@tempdima}{4.5\pgfutil@tempdima}}%
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{4.5\pgfutil@tempdima}{-4.5\pgfutil@tempdima}}%
```

The `backgrounds` library and its `gridded` option is only used to show where TikZ places the arrows.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=false]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\makeatletter
\pgfarrowsdeclare{oplus}{oplus}{%
  \pgfarrowsleftextend{+-.5\pgflinewidth}
  \pgfutil@tempdima=0.4pt%
  \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by.2\pgflinewidth%
  \pgfutil@tempdimb=9\pgfutil@tempdima\advance\pgfutil@tempdimb by.5\pgflinewidth
  \pgfarrowsrightextend{+\pgfutil@tempdimb}%
}{%
  \pgfutil@tempdima=0.4pt%
  \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by.2\pgflinewidth%
  \pgfsetdash{}{+0pt}%
  \pgfpathcircle{\pgfqpoint{4.5\pgfutil@tempdima}{0bp}}{4.5\pgfutil@tempdima}%
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0bp}{0bp}}%
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{9\pgfutil@tempdima}{0bp}}%
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{4.5\pgfutil@tempdima}{4.5\pgfutil@tempdima}}%
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{4.5\pgfutil@tempdima}{-4.5\pgfutil@tempdima}}%
  \pgfusepathqstroke
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tikz[gridded]\draw[oplus-oplus] (0,0) -- +(right:1) -- +(up:1);
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, that what's exactly what I was looking for :)
If I had to do any remark would be to put the \pgfutil@tempdima=0.4pt% to 0.8pt so that in an UML diagram is well seen the oplus, but all in all, thank you